# WebSocket connection to Docker container via Apache reverse proxy issue

Tags: docker, apache, websocket, reverse-proxy

I am facing difficulties setting up a WebSocket connection through an Apache reverse proxy to a WebSocket server running inside a Docker container. Here's the scenario:

- WebSocket server: The WebSocket server is hosted inside a Docker container.
- Docker container configuration: The WebSocket server in the Docker container is configured to listen for WebSocket connections on a specific path, e.g., `/ws/chat/1694406657943/`.
- Apache reverse proxy: I have configured Apache as a reverse proxy to forward WebSocket requests to the WebSocket server inside the Docker container.
  Issue:
  When attempting to connect to ws://abc.com/ws/chat/1694406657943/, I encounter the error message "WebSocket connection failed."

What I've already tried:

- Confirmed that the WebSocket server inside the Docker container is running and correctly configured to handle WebSocket connections on the specified path.
- Checked Apache error logs, but I couldn't find any relevant errors or warnings.
- Ensured that the Docker container's port is correctly exposed to the host machine.
- **Verified that the WebSocket server works correctly when accessed directly on the host machine**.

I'm looking for guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this WebSocket connection issue through the Apache reverse proxy.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com


        ServerName abc.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@abc.com

     ProxyRequests Off

     <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
     </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/


    ProxyPass /ws ws://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://127.0.0.1:8000/
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/abc.com.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/abc.com.access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

[image: web error]

Answer (score 0):

After checking the Docker log as well as the Apache log, I managed to fix it by changing the Apache WebSocket configuration according to the web URL request

```
ProxyPass /ws ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws
ProxyPassReverse /ws ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws
```